# My render is looking completely different from viewport shading and render preview

Tags: rendering, texturing, node-editor

For context I am following the blender guru anvil tutorial. When I finished my anvil some areas in the render look smooth. I tried tinkering with the textures and its values but there are no changes to the smooth areas. I even tried texture painting in the area and it shows in the viewport but not the render.
[image: This is my render]

[image: This is my render preview]

[image: These are my nodes]

[image: This is my uv smart unwrap just in case]

Comment: It looks like you have some objects hidden in the viewport - things hidden in the viewport will still be visible in renders. To exclude the objects you want to keep hidden from renders, move those objects to a separate collection then disable (not hide) the collection by un-checking the checkbox.

Comment: I complete forgot about that! Thank you so much!